python. flet. Как в режиме WEB получить содержимое загруженного файла
У меня была простая цель, приложение в режиме WEB по кнопке открывает выбор файла, я выбираю себе файл конфига например и содержимое файла появляется в TextField.
Вот скрипт заготовка:
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.padding = ft.Padding(top=60, bottom=60, left=250, right=250)

    def on_dialog_result(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        content = str(e.data) + "\n" + str(e.files)
        text_field.value = text_field.value + "\n" + content
        text_field.update()

    file_picker = ft.FilePicker(on_result=on_dialog_result)
    page.overlay.append(file_picker)
    page.update()

    text_field = ft.TextField(multiline=True, min_lines=10, max_lines=15, border_color=ft.colors.WHITE)

    page.add(
        text_field,
        ft.Row([ft.IconButton(icon=ft.icons.FILE_DOWNLOAD, bgcolor=ft.colors.INDIGO,
                              on_click=lambda _: file_picker.pick_files())],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END
        )
    )

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.WEB_BROWSER)

Для меня это оказалось непосильной задачей.
Помогите разобраться?

def extract_second_value_with_quotes(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                # Разделяем строку на части по пробелам (или другому разделителю)
                parts = line.strip().split()
                # Проверяем, есть ли хотя бы два элемента в строке
                if len(parts) >= 2:
                    # Извлекаем второе значение и добавляем кавычки
                    second_value = '"' + parts[1] + '"'
                    print(second_value)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Файл {filename} не найден.")

Пример использования функции
filename = 'example.txt'
extract_second_value_with_quotes(filename)


Ну тут явно не то, вопрос про flet и нужен вывод в текстовое поле, а у вас принты, плюс какие-то манипуляции непонятные, хотя по идее нужно просто файл как есть вывести.
